# How to handle the exceeded length of jwt access token in auth0

Tags: jwt, auth0, user-permissions

I am using the auth0 for managing the authentication and authorization for the users.

The access token that is generated the auth0 while user login is used for determining the authenticity of the user.
As per the algorithm, I am adding all the permissions in this token. So that whenever API gets called, this token can be sent in headers and there could be validity check in the backend too.

But as the application gets bigger, the number of permissions also increased.
So the length of **jwt token exceeded the limit** that was defined by auth0.
Basically the API used to get the profile of the user that is provided by auth0 gets failed.

What can be the other approaches to resolve this error?

Comment: Which limit exactly is exceeded? And what are you storing in the JWT that it gets so big?

Comment: The length of token is getting larger. I am storing permissions in jwt so that I can authorize the user in backend too.